# Advice for getting a pointer to an object from a vector stored inside a class

Tags: c++, class-design, const-correctness

```
class Element {
    class Point {
        private:
            double x;
            double y;
        public:
            //getters/setters for x and y
    };
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Point> values;
    public:
        void insertValue(unsigned int index, double x, double y);
        ...
};

class Collection {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Element> elements;
    public:
        ...
        ...
        Element* elementAt(unsigned int index) const {
            return const_cast<Element*>(&elements.at(index));
        }
};
```

What I need is to get an Element in a certain index from the collection to do operations like `Element::insertValues`. It is a bad practice doing it as it's done in the `Collection::elementAt` method (using const_cast)?
Is it better to remove the const qualifier from the method? I marked the method const since the method itself does not modify the object.

Comment: Sure. If you want to be able to modify it. Don't make the method a const. Also, the fact the method is const doesn't mean you can't return a pointer to a non const. But you should be consistent and not make the method a const.

Comment: If you believe this function shouldn't participate in modifying the object, it should return a `const Element*`.  If instead you have reasons to make it return an `Element*`, _those reasons_ are why the function should not be `const`.  You can also write both versions.

Comment: Almost _always_ when you are using `const_cast` to solve a problem then _you_ are the problem. The vector is const because the method is const, and therefore the stuff it contains is const. So you should return a const pointer. Even better, a const reference. What you're doing right now potentially breaks the contract of object constness and can result in undefined behavior. If you want a modifiable value, then create a non-const overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual idiom for this is to have two methods, a `const` one and a non-`const` one. In this case one returns a `const Element *`, and the other one returns an `Element *`, keeping everything const-correct.

```
        const Element* elementAt(unsigned int index) const {
            return &elements.at(index);
        }

        Element* elementAt(unsigned int index)  {
            return &elements.at(index);
        }
```

Yes, it is true that this leads to some code duplication. Such is life, noone has ever accused C++ of being compact and concise.

P.S.: you didn't ask this, but an even better idiom would be to return a reference, rather than a pointer. `std::vector::at` returns a reference, why shouldn't your pinch-hitter do the same?